# How to send all the bitmap images to sdcard in android

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

To share the image via MMS the code is working. What i have done is, converted  drawable image to bitmap and saved in sd card. and retrieved to send through intent, this is for one image, i'm struck in sending all the images in an array to sd card.
in below code i have placed the images in an array from drawable and converted all the 4 images to bitmap, how to send this 4 images to sdcard ?

```
 private void doSendIntent(String subject, String text) {
      try {
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
       sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text); 
   sendIntent.setType("image/png");

   ArrayList<Integer> myImageList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    myImageList.add(R.drawable.gicon);
    myImageList.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    myImageList.add(R.drawable.loadin);
    myImageList.add(R.drawable.splash);


    Bitmap bbicon;
    bbicon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.cordova.getActivity().getResources(),
            R.drawable.gicon);
    bbicon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.cordova.getActivity().getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    bbicon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.cordova.getActivity().getResources(),
            R.drawable.loadin);
    bbicon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.cordova.getActivity().getResources(),
            R.drawable.splash);


    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();          
    OutputStream outStream = null;

    File f = new File(extStorageDirectory + "/Download/",
            "gicon.png");
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
        bbicon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();

         System.out.println("ssssssssssssssssss");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    }

    //RETRIEVING IMAGES FROM SDCARD

    File fl = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/Download/", "gicon.png");

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(fl);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    this.cordova.startActivityForResult(this, sendIntent, 0); 

      }
      catch(Exception e) 
      {
       System.out.println(" no error here");

       e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code.

```
private void copyAssets() {
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
String[] files = null;
try {
    files = assetManager.list("");
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
}
for(String filename : files) {
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
      in = assetManager.open(filename);
      out = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/" + filename);
      copyFile(in, out);
      in.close();
      in = null;
      out.flush();
      out.close();
      out = null;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }       
  }
}
private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
   int read;
   while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
   out.write(buffer, 0, read);
 }
}
```

Take below permission from Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```